# Current context value is not rendered from Usercontrol to .aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

i have default.aspx page and one user control.
usercontrol is having following code for multiple file uploads.
now the problem is when i add a file for upload that current context file is not giving me any value it is still zero i guess because it is rendering from user control.

what should i do?

My Usercontrol `UPLOAD.ASCX`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FileUpload.ascx.cs" Inherits="FileUpload" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addfile").click(function () {
            $("#dvfiles").append("<input name=" + i + "fu type=file /><a href=#>remove</a><br>");
            i++;
        });

        $("#dvfiles a").live('click', function () {
            $(this).prev("input[type=file]").remove();
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    $(document).submit(function () {
        var flag = true;
        $("#dvfiles input[type=file]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).css("background", "Red");
                flag = false;
            }
        });
        return flag;
    });        
</script>

<div id="Fileuploader">
<a href="#" id="addfile">Attach a file..</a><br />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"
    onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
</div>
```

`UPLOAD.ASCX.CS`

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HttpFileCollection filecolln = Request.Files; 
        //here i don't get values of current files.
      // this is zero. because of this following if condition failed 
       //please help here
        if (filecolln.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filecolln.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = filecolln[i];
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                }
            }
            lblMessage.Text = "Uploaded Successfully!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "No files selected!";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

`Default.aspx code`

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"    
    Inherits="_Default" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="ucFileuploader" tagName="Fileuploader" src="FileUpload.ascx"    %> 

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ucFileuploader:Fileuploader ID="Fileuploder" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you realise that asp.net has had a FileUpload control that you can use since asp.net 2.0? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Comment: "it goes to 'Default.aspx#'" ? what does this mean? What are your errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using javascript an id names.

so when you have control with id addfile in .aspx it is rendered as is, 
but when you have control with id addfile in user control with id Fileuploader, 
than the rendered id is **Fileuploader_addfile**, 
so change id name in java script with the proper id.

To chechk what is name of rendered id, open page in browser, open source of the page and find you element and copy id into java script. 
Change all ids in java script with rendered id names.

Comment: I checked into page source name is 'addfile' :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it could be this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Which should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't matter , I guess something need to changed with javascript

Comment: perhaps you could post up the rest of your ascx file so we can see the markup?